# How to convert a single object or a set into a set?

Tags: python

There's a method as follows:

```
def send_message(
    content: str,
    slack_conn_ids: Union[SlackConnection, Set[SlackConnection]],
    send_only_in_production: bool = True,
):
   ...
   if isinstance(slack_conn_ids, set):
      set_slack_conn_ids = slack_conn_ids
   elif isinstance(slack_conn_ids, SlackConnection):
      set_slack_conn_ids = {slack_conn_ids}
   else:
      raise ValueError("`slack_conn_ids` should be of type `SlackConnection` or `Set[SlackConnection]`"
        )
   ...
```

Can this code be simplified, implemented more idiomatically?

Comment: What you have is fine, assuming it's a good idea to support sets or single objects in the first place. (I'm of the opinion that it is not.)

Comment: (Though I wouldn't bother adding a runtime check that duplicates what `mypy` would be able to catch. Related, do you really need a *set*? Unless you plan on mutating the set inside your function, I would say no. I'm assuming the only thing you are going to do is iterate over the set, in which case `typing.Iterable` would suffice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. Let the caller be responsible for providing a set, even if that set only contains one connection.

```
def send_message(
    content: str,
    slack_conn_ids: Set[SlackConnection],
    send_only_in_production: bool = True,
):
   
   ...


s = SlackConnection(...)
send_message("hi", {s})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching.

```py
match slack_conn_ids:
    case set():
        set_slack_conn_ids = slack_conn_ids
    case SlackConnection():
        set_slack_conn_ids = { slack_conn_ids }
    case _:
        raise ValueError("`slack_conn_ids` should be of type `SlackConnection` or `Set[SlackConnection]`")
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is already very simplified, it is impossible to come out with something worth the difference.

Here is how I would design that code:

```
if isinstance(slack_conn_ids, SlackConnection) or isinstance(slack_conn_ids, set):
    try:
        slack_conn_ids = {slack_conn_ids}
    except TypeError:
        pass
else:
    raise ValueError("`slack_conn_ids` should be of type `SlackConnection` or `Set[SlackConnection]`")
```

**Explanation:**

1. Check in one-line if input is approved.
2. Change variable slack_conn_ids to set if object. If already set, everything okay. No need to waste memory creating new variables and assigning more than needed.

Comment: Having an exception thrown is much worse than saving a couple of lines

Comment: This doesn't even save any lines.

Comment: You check if `slack_conn_ids` is a set, but then ignore that information to try to add a set to a set. The exception is entirely avoidable.

Comment: @chepner The user wanted the function to only accept an object or a set, we need to confirm it is a set, but don't need to make any changes to it.And Steven, I didn't in any part of my answer say that this is better or worse, and I don't understand how using that exception throw is worse. In terms of what or whom?

Comment: If you confirm it's a set, there's no reason to go through the effort of trying to define `{slack_conn_ids}`; you *know* it's going to raise a `TypeError`. There's no benefit to this approach, only the overhead of catching an avoidable exception.

Comment: At the very least, `isinstance` can take a tuple of classes: `if isinstance(slack_conn, (SlackConnection, set)): ...`